# Spring Source Suite (STS) 3.0.0 Rel automatically closes once the IDE is loaded

Tags: java, spring, ide, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Needed help in resolving the issue related to STS 3.0.0 IDE.

When I open the IDE it

1. prompts for the workspace location
2. After giving the location it loads the necessary plug-ins
3. Opens the IDE with the default perspective
4. After that it immediately closes off.

Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 64bit
- Java: 1.7

Note: Latest versions are there, because of the project dependencies I am using the STS 3.0.0 Release.
I have tried with STS 3.6 RC1, it is working properly

Cheers,
Raj

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and I just uninstalled JDK and then reinstalled it then this issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try with different jdk like 6 .If its still not working try in another operation system or different version it.

Comment: thanks @SabaRish. Will try it out with different version. But need to know is this directly related to java, as I have already java7&8 installed and updating the alternatives as i needed.

Comment: since its is a older version of ide its worth trying with lower version of java like 6

Comment: Have tried installing the Java6, this time it was not closing but hangs up permanently and I need to kill it manually :(

Comment: Other things worth trying on Ubuntu: 1) use Oracle JDK instead of openjdk it tends to be more stable. 2) set environmentvariable 'SWT_GTK3=0'. I found Gtk3 implementation of SWT is not as stable than Gtk2. Though it usually doesn't cause JVM crashes, I have seen it happen.

Comment: What you describe sounds like a JVM crash. There is probably a crashlog file somewhere, probably your user's home directory. Its name something like "hs_err_pid<pid>.log" where 'pid' is a number (process-id of crashed process). This file might provide a clue on the cause of the crash.